# Ignorar ponto em uma Query

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

estou tentando executar a seguinte Query:

```
select codigo from cliente where codigo ilike '%99.999.999%';
```

Achei que colocando o `ilike`, ele ignoraria tudo, pontos e acentuações mas me enganei.

Em meu sistema, tenho uma tela de consulta onde eu prefiro que o usuário não precise digitar os pontos...
Quando ele pesquisar um CPF por exemplo

Detalhe: Utilizo essa query em um TextChanged de um TextBox

Como eu poderia fazer essa query para ignorar os ponto?

Comment: monte a query sem os pontos..

Comment: Em meu sistema, tenho uma tela de consulta onde eu prefiro que o usuário não precise digitar os pontos...
Quando ele pesquisar um CPF por exemplo

Comment: Retire o ponto quando passa o texto da tela para a query?

Comment: Estou fazendo essa consulta em um campo no evento TextChanged. Na hora que ele digita, ja vai fazendo a consulta

Comment: se esse valor é uma entrada de um usuário, basta remover os pontos antes de jogá-lo na query. Pode fazer isso no próprio C# ou na SQL..  O fato do dado provir de um evento "TextChanged", não faz diferença..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função **REPLACE** para remover os pontos. Segue abaixo exemplo.

```
REPLACE('99.999.999', '.','')
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!

Answer (score 2):

Evite injetar complexidade de aplicação em querys sql. Isso dificulta a manutenção, porque reaproveitamento de SQL (strings) é praticamente 0.

O ideal serial a construção de um objeto Cpf:

```
public class Cpf{

     private string _valorSemMascara;

     public string CpfComMascara {
         get{
              // retorna _valorSemMascara incluindo máscara por concatenação
          }
          set{
             // remove máscara de 'value' e atribui valor em _valorSemMascara
          }

     }

     public string CpfSemMascara {

          get{
             return _valorSemMascara;
          }
          set{
             _valorSemMascara = value;
          }
     }

}
```

Este objeto seria reaproveitado em diversas situações dentro do seu sistema.

Você pode utilizá-lo desde no seu 'text_changed' até no ponto de inclusões, alterações e obtenções (selects).

Somente na situação que você descreveu e em um CRUD, quantas vezes você iria repetir o método 'REPLACE' na query? E se resolver mudar de SGBD? Vai deixar sua query presa ao PostgreSql?

Comment: Obrigado!!!! ^^